# Reporting Services 2008: Virtual directories not visible in IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I'm having some problems with Reporting Services on **Windows Server 2008 Standard**.

I've installed server 2008 as a standalone webserver (with roles/features of an web application server).  On top of that, I've installed **Sql Server 2008 Standard with Reporting Services** (and the rest of the BI tools).

**Problem is, I want to modify the rights on the virtual directories.  However, the virtual directories aren't appearing in IIS 7 management tool.**

I can connect to reporting services, albeit only with the local windows admin account.  I can download Report Builder fine from an session on the server (but not from any clients).

I've tried removing the default website from IIS, and that stops the reporting services website from working.

**The machine (a VM) isn't for production use - it's used on a closed network internally for testing and development purposes.**  I need to be able to let my fellow developers login without a password, and they must be able to install ReportBuilder 2.0.  Must not be linked to a domain or active directory in any form.

Google isn't much help, the results suggest I modify the virtual directory

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

Answer (score 3):

SSRS 2008 doesn't use IIS to host the folders.  SSRS hosts them itself using http.sys.  You can connect to the folders and modify the permissions from within the Website if you log on as an admin.

SSRS 2008 doesn't support anonymous login like SSRS 2005 did (which I assume is what you are trying to do).

Comment: So where are the folders?  How do I connect and modify the permissions?

Comment: Connect locally to the reporting services website.  Select the folder you want to edit, then click the properties tab.  Then select Security from the left.  From there you can add the users or groups that you want to access the site.

Comment: In my case the reporting services website is blank except for headers at the top.  I was thinking I needed to add permissions somewhere else first to make any objects show up?

Comment: I went ahead and made my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228872/ssrs-2008-reporting-services-webpage-is-blank-except-for-headers

Answer (score 0):

[Here You can find programmer side of story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671694/passing-credentials-to-sql-report-server-2008)

What We did is:

That We make new web sites hosted on IIS which has embed ReportViewer.
ReportViewer component is set to login and show report from SSRS 2008.
Maybe it can be used as one of suggestions to solve anonymous login